I’m developing an Android Library that's have some external dependency but does not automatically download its dependencies from the dependent app
Developing Android Library that have Some Defendency like this
// Retrofit and Coroutines dependencies
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")

    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    kapt("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.6.8")

    implementation("com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:3.1.0") {
        exclude(group = "org.json", module = "json")
    }

    val nav_version = "2.7.7"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")
    implementation("com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0")

When i build ,aar file with this command ./gradlew assembleRelease with gradle task . Don't add those library with .aar file.
I need to add those library with Parent Project after that run my application with library. But when not integrating with my parent app build.gradle file with those library give me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder .
Give me suggestion what exactly need to do for adding all those defendency with my library or .aar file.
Thakns in Advance.
When i build ,aar file with this command ./gradlew assembleRelease with gradle task . Don't add those library with .aar file.
I need to add those library with Parent Project after that run my application with library. But when not integrating with my parent app build.gradle file with those library give me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder .
Give me suggestion what exactly need to do for adding all those defendency with my library or .aar file.
Thakns in Advance.
